# PC Monitor flickering.Display goes to one side and the flickered part goes black

Tags: display

My monitor is flickering.Whenever it flickers the display screen goes to one side and flicked part turns to black..It flickers like when any cell phone vibrates near monitor and the monitor also vibrates.

But that ain't my problem...Hep me!!

Comment: What type and model of monitor? And how is it connected to the computer?

Comment: @Dan D....Sir,It's a CRT monitor. The power supplier plug is connected to UPS and the the other wire as usually connected between monitor and CPU